# DataTable fixed header not working for scrollable table

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

I've been working with dataTables for a short period of time and I have a DataTable with two columns:

```
TableVehUsage = $("#TableVehUsage ").DataTable({
    data: [],
    ordering: true,
    paginate: false,
    "info": false,
    fixedHeader: {header: true},
    columns: [
        { data: "Vehicle", title: "Vehicle" },
        { data: "Serial", title: "Serial" }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": 0,
            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                // If it is rendering the cell contents
                if (type === 'display') {
                    switch (data) {
                        case "-":
                            return "-";
                        default:
                            if (full.IsOnSale == true)
                                return '<span style="color:red" onclick="ToParentTab(' + full.Id + ')">' + data + '</span>';
                            else
                                return '<span onclick="ToParentTab(' + full.Id + ')">' + data + '</span>';
                    }
                }
                return (isNaN(data)) ? -1 : +data;
            }
        } }]
});
```

I have some situation when all the data don't fit in the page and the user needs to scroll down to see all the info. I've tried to use [Fixed Header](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/header_footer.html) by adding to my javascript the line `fixedHeader: {header: true}` and in the html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.2/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.2/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
```

But is not working for me :(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I found a DataTable plugin that may be of help.  Information on it is located at https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/

Using this, my definition looks like this:

```
  var table1 = $('#example').DataTable({ paging: true,   
      scrollY:        200,
      deferRender:    true,
      scroller:       true });
```

I made a jsFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/oywvh1ek/6/

Comment: Yeah... that's the same thing I've tried but I was trying to avoid adding a scroll for the body because depending on the screen resolution the header does not fit that's why I was looking for the FixedHeader :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your data in a different variable with only the 'value' part of the key-value pair in it. For example, in the case of 
{"vehicle":"Audi"}, 
your 'data' variable should have only ["Audi"] in it.

The below code worked perfectly for me.

```
         $("<your_table_name>").DataTable({
                data:data,
                fixedHeader:true,
                "scrollX": true,
                "scrollY": "200px",
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                columns: [
                        { title: 'Vehicle' },
                        { title: 'Serial' }
                    ]
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where my fixedHeader was working until I got about halfway down the page, then it disappeared.  Here is what I did to get it working:

At the top of my JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    DrawDataTable();

    //This enables the table header to stick to the top of the page when the user is scrolling
    var employeeData = $('#employee-table').DataTable();
    employeeData.fixedHeader.adjust();
});
```

Then in the same JS file, in my jQuery ajax call, I had to add the line of code that says `"fixedHeader": true`
[image]

Finally, in my HTML file, I had to include the following in my `<head>` section:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.12.1/fh-3.2.4/r-2.3.0/datatables.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.12.1/fh-3.2.4/r-2.3.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Do not forget that you will also need to include whatever Bootstrap, JavaScript or jQuery scripts or style sheets in the head as well.